# NGXS Selectors bug or am i losing my mind?

Tags: angular, ngxs

```
 @Selector()
    static broken(state: AuthStateModel): string | null {
      return state.token;
    }

 @Selector()
    static token(state: AuthStateModel): string | null {
      return state.token;
    }

  isAuth$:Observable<boolean> = this.store.selectOnce(state => state.auth.token);
  isTest$:Observable<boolean> = this.store.selectOnce(state => state.auth.broken);

  this.isAuth$.subscribe(x=>{
      console.log(x);
  });

  this.isTest$.subscribe(x=>{
    console.log(x);
  });
```

[image]

First one is correctly logging token from state while seccond one is logging undefined. I have no idea what is happening. Have i finaly lost my mind?

Edit:

```
   
@Selector()          
isAuthenticated(state: AuthStateModel): boolean {
    if(state.token !=null)
        return this.tokenService.isValidToken(state.token);
    return false;
}
```

How would I return this selector?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's pretty common to lose mind over overlooking something.

You're not using the selectors you declared but instead you're using different ones. And I don't think there is a `broken` property in the `auth` state.

Code causing trouble:

```
this.store.selectOnce(state => state.auth.broken);
```

I suggest you reference the static selector method:

```
this.store.selectOnce(Component.broken);
```

Where `Component` is the name of the class with the static selector members (not included in your code sample).

Comment: Seems like I can't comprehend how ngxs selectors work. I guess i will just create an action instead of selector in my post edit. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Actions and selectors are completely different way :-)